Elliptic curves with same $a_p$ for every $p$ are isogenous
If two curves E,F satisfy $\#E(\mathbb{F}_p) = \#F(\mathbb{F}_p)$ for each large prime then E and F are isogenous (conversely, two isogenous curves must have the same values of $\#E(F_p)$ for every $p$ not dividing their discriminant, though that is a bit simpler). This is a theorem of Faltings, his original proof appears to be found in

G. Faltings, Endlichkeitssatze fur abelsche Varietaten uber
Zahlkorpern, Invent. Math. 73 (1983), 349-366.

Would anyone have additional references about this fact? I am particularly looking for English references since I don't read German. Thank you.

Do you want to know Faltings' proof?  E.g., now it's a simple consequence of modularity.

I would just like to understand why it is true. Modularity is a very hard theorem... Is there a particular part of a text you know that clarifies this fact?

@Kimball can you explain how it follows from modularity?

Let's say $f_1, f_2$ are the associated modular forms.  Then for almost all $p$, $a_p(f_1) = a_p(f_2)$.  This implies $f_1 = f_2$ by Strong Multiplicity One.  Hence your original elliptic curves must correspond to the same cusp form, and therefore be isogenous.

@mathmo123 this fact is often built into the statement of the the modularity theorem (a correspondence between weight 2 modular forms and isogeny classes of elliptic curves). I don't know very much about modularity so I don't know if the known proofs offer their own insight into this fact or if they rely on previously known proofs.

@Kimball I guess I'm worried about the last line: can one show that two elliptic curves corresponding to the same cusp form are isogenous, without invoking Faltings' theorem?

@Rodrigo The specific Theorem of Faltings that you're looking for is his proof that, if $E, F$ are elliptic curves over a number field $K$, then the natural map injective map $\mathrm{Hom}(E, F)\otimes\mathbb Q_\ell\to \mathrm{Hom}{G_K}(V\ell(E),V_\ell(F))$ is actually an isomorphism. Under your hypothesis, the Galois representations are isomorphic (by Chebotarev and Brauer--Nesbitt), so the right hand side is non-trivial. Thus the left hand-side is non-trivial, so there is an isogeny from $E$ to $F$.

@Mathmo123 I think it follows from Shimura's work associating abelian subvarieties $A_f$ of $J_0(N)$ to modular forms $f$ but I'd need to look at the details again.

If you're just asking about elliptic curves over a finite field, then you can appeal to Tate's isogeny theorem. I believe the original reference is his paper "Endomorphisms of abelian varieties over finite fields." In any case, the hammer you need is essentially the isomorphism mentioned in a comment above, but for curves over a finite field. The precise statement is in Silverman's "Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves" (chapter III, theorem 7.7.a). With this tool in hand, it's just matter of looking at the characteristic polynomial of Frobenius for the two curves.
